# Deserialize YAML to JAVA

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a YAML File with following data and i want to Deserialize that into java Object.

```
connector:
  provider: ABCD
  nodes: 
  -  1.1.2.1
  -  1.2.2.8
  maxconnection: 1
  minconnection: 1
```

1.First i created a class called Connector where i have defined all the variable like `Provider`, `Nodes`, `maxconnections`, `Minconnections`.
2.Then i created a class called group and call the Connector class.
3.then in the main function tried to load the yaml file and call it.

But i got Null pointer exception Error

```
#Connector Class
public static class connector {

            private String provider;

            private String[]  nodes;

            private int max_connections;

            private int min_connections; 

            public String getprovider() {
                return provider;
            }
            public void setprovider(String provider) {
                this.provider = provider;
            }
           public String[] getnodes() {
              return nodes;
            }
            public void setnodes( String[] nodes) {
              this.nodes = nodes;
            }            
            public int getmax_connections() {
              return max_connections;
            }
            public void setmax_connections(int max_connections) {
              this.max_connections = max_connections;
            }
            public int getmin_connections() {
              return min_connections;
            }
            public void setmin_connections(int min_connections) {
              this.min_connections = min_connections;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "connector: {provider: " + this.provider + ", nodes: " + this.nodes + ",max_connections: " + this.max_connections +",min_connections: " + this.min_connections +"}";
            }


#Group class

        public static class Group {
            private ArrayList<connector> connector;

            public ArrayList<connector> getconnector() {
                return connector;
            }           

            public void setconnector(ArrayList<connector> connector) {
                this.connector = connector;
            }
        }

#main Class

public static void main(String[] args) {

            final URL resource = YamlConf.class.getResource("demo.yaml");
            final Constructor peopleContructor = new Constructor(Group.class);
            final TypeDescription peopleDescription = new TypeDescription(connector.class);
            peopleDescription.putMapPropertyType("connector", connector.class, Object.class);
            peopleContructor.addTypeDescription(peopleDescription);

            final Yaml yaml = new Yaml(peopleContructor);
            try {
                final Group group = (Group) yaml.load(resource.openStream());
                for (final connector connector : group.getconnector()) {
                    System.out.println(connector);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please read [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/24100776#24100776).

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Jackson, you could use [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) with the [`YAMLFactory`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformats-text/javadoc/yaml/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory.html). Under the hood, it will use the [`SnakeYAML`](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) library. For the required dependencies, refer to the [`jackson-dataformats-text`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text) project documentation.

You could define your classes as follows:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Content {

    private Connector connector;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Connector {

    private String provider;

    private List<String> nodes;

    @JsonProperty("maxconnection")
    private Integer maxConnections;

    @JsonProperty("minconnection")
    private Integer minConnections;
}
```

The [`@Getter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter), [`@Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) and [`@NoArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) annotations are from the [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) project. They will generate getters, setters and the default constructor for your. If you don't want to use Lombok, simply implement those methods.

Then read your YAML file:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
Content content = mapper.readValue(yamlFile, Content.class);
```

---

Depending on your needs, you could consider a `Map<String, Object>` to hold the values:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> type = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> content = mapper.readValue(yamlFile, type);
```